# Conversión de valores de cadena a valores originales en una solicitud GET en Express

Tags: typescript, express, get

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Express y estoy trabajando en una solicitud GET donde recibo valores en forma de cadena a través de parámetros. Mi objetivo es transformar esos valores en sus valores originales antes de pasarlos a la función creditNoteUseCase.

Los valores que puedo recibir son solo números o el valor "undefined". Actualmente, estoy intentando convertir el parámetro user a un número utilizando la función parseInt, como se muestra en el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
export const getCreditNotes = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        let params = req.query;
        console.log('>>> ', params.user);
        parseInt(params.user);
        
        const data = await creditNoteUseCase.getCreditNotes(params);
        return res.json({
            ok: true,
            data
        });

    } catch (err) {
        return res.json({
            ok: false,
            message: err
        });
    }
};
```

Sin embargo, me gustaría saber si existen mejores prácticas o enfoques más elegantes para realizar esta conversión, en lugar de simplemente utilizar condicionales. Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o consejo sobre cómo mejorar este proceso de conversión.

Aquí está el objeto que recibo en la solicitud GET:

```
{
  "distributor": "undefined",
  "user": "undefined",
  "type": "undefined",
  "page": "1",
  "size": "10"
}
```

Aprecio su ayuda y orientación en este tema, gracias